# Laravel full-page component with filament form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm trying to use a full-page livewire component along with a Filament form. I'd like it to update the database automatically after a user selects from the dropdown, so I'm using `live()`.

The call is made in the network tab in dev tools to `livewire/update`, but the field isn't updated in the database.

I've tried following [the docs](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/adding-a-form-to-a-livewire-component#setting-up-the-livewire-component), but it seems to indicate this all happens seamlessly without having to have like a submit method or anything. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

What is the process for creating form on a full-page livewire component, preferrably one that updates without clicking a submit button?

Here's my component:

```
<?php


class Config extends Page implements HasForms
{
    use InteractsWithForms;

    protected static ?string $title = 'Config';

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-cog-8-tooth';

    protected static string $view = 'filament.app.pages.location.config';

    protected static ?string $slug = 'location/{location}/config';

    protected static bool $shouldRegisterNavigation = false;

    public Location $location;
    public array $accounts = [];
    public array $data = [];

    public function mount(Location $location)
    {
        $this->location = $location->load('config');

        if (empty($this->location->config)) {
            $this->location->config()->create();
            $this->location = $location->load('config');
        }


        $this->getAccounts();

        $this->form->fill(['field_id' => $this->location->config->field_id]);
    }

    

    public function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                FieldSet::make()->relationship('config')->schema([
                    Select::make('field_id')->label('Account Mapping')
                        ->options($this->accounts)
                        ->preload()
                        ->searchable()
                        ->live()
                        ->loadingMessage('Loading accounts...'),

                ]),
            ])->statePath('data')
            ->model($this->location);
    }
}
```

and here's the view file:

```
<x-filament::page>
    {{ $this->form }}
</x-filament::page>
```